# How does sGP of Ebola virus help it to evade host humoral immunity?

Tags: immunology, virus, virology

During Ebola infection, the viruses secret a lot of sGP. What's its function? Since anti GP antibodies are effective at inhibiting Ebola infection, wouldn't sGP stimulate host immune system to produce more anti GP antibodies? Why does Ebola virus expose its weakness deliberately?